# Ace-editor in Android Chrome browser - Shift key deletes a symbol

Tags: ace-editor

I'm using prebuilt ace-editor from https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/src

Here's my HTML page (almost the same as example on http://ace.c9.io):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Editor</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #editor {
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<pre id="editor"></pre>

<script src="ace/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/groovy");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Running at http://cornplay.com/lab/editor.html

The problem: whenever I press Shift key on Android virtual keyboard, it deletes last symbol instead of switching to uppercase.

Here's the video: https://vimeo.com/165671675

What I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same behavior: https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html